# error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

These are error about it

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/luckyxmobile/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Family_Health_Tracker-blmdlgtkbfuvvxdcozttgzspcguc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/luckyxmobile/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Family_Health_Tracker-blmdlgtkbfuvvxdcozttgzspcguc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MGSwipeTableCell'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/luckyxmobile/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Family_Health_Tracker-blmdlgtkbfuvvxdcozttgzspcguc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MJRefresh'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/luckyxmobile/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Family_Health_Tracker-blmdlgtkbfuvvxdcozttgzspcguc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iRate'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/luckyxmobile/Documents/code/Family Health Tracker-master/Pods/UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA/umsdk_IOS_analytics_no-idfa_v3.6.7/UMAnalytics_Sdk_3.6.7'
ld: library not found for -lMGSwipeTableCell
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Who can help me ,thx

Comment: did you see all .h files in Build phases -> compile Sources. If not  then manually add that files. OR Relink all libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relink those things "Build settings->Linking->Other Linker Flags"

1. AFNetworking
2. MGSwipeTableCell
3. MJRefresh
4. iRate

Is it your project? Sometime , the code people shared in Internet could lack of some lib.

Comment: there are not these options,these are pods

Answer (score 1):

You can relink those things "Build settings->Linking->Other Linker Flags"
Add:$(inherited)

Comment: Select your target project:Build settings->Linking->Other Linker Flags Add:$(inherited)

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit scheme as shown below.

[image]

Then uncheck all other targets except your main target under build tab.

[image]

Comment: i delete about test and UItest ,but it is doesn't work